# Setting theme options in YAML header for beamer presentation?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, beamer

I am making a beamer presentation in RStudio, using the Metropolis theme. I would like to use some options, say *sectionpage = none*, but I don't know where to put the option in the YAML header.

I just have the basics:

```
---
title: "TemplatePresentation"
author: "MightyMauz"
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    theme: metropolis
---
```

How can I pass metropolis theme options?

Comment: Use the YAML option `classoption`. https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format#latex_options

Comment: I think the `classoption` is for passing something to `\documentclass`, not to pass an option to a theme

Comment: Ah I misread your question. Anyhow, the answer posted solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `header-includes` instead to declare what theme you want to use:

```
---
title: "TemplatePresentation"
author: "MightyMauz"
classoption: "portrait"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
  - \usetheme[sectionpage = none]{metropolis}
---
```